# Theorem to show trajectories of differential equations are close after small change to initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

Consider two solutions(or trajectories), say $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$, of a system of differential equaions. That is,
$$
x_1'(t)=x_2'(t)=f(x,t), t\ge0.
$$

Also, $\|x_2(0)-x_1(0)\|<\epsilon$ for some small constant $\epsilon$. So, $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ can be regarded as two trajectories starting with two close initial conditions in the system . I would like to ask is there any theorem to show that under what conditions, we can say $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are very close if the perturbation in the initial condition is small. For example, is any theorem to say something like this?

For every $\delta>0$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that if $\|x_2(0)-x_1(0)\|<\epsilon$, then we have $\|x_2(t)-x_1(t)\|<\delta, \forall t\ge0$.

I know there is Lyapunov stability to show the stability of the equilibrium point. However, I want the something stronger than that. It is about the "stability of the trajectories". It would be greatly appreciated if you could help with this question.

Comment: Well, definition of Lyapunov stability can be applied not only to equilibrium points, but to any other trajectories as well. And what you've written is an exact definition of Lyapunov stable trajectory. For some types of trajectories (like steady states and limit cycles) there is quite well established theory that can answer this question. When you ask trajectories to be close for all $t > 0$ then it's full, general and not straightforward problem.

Comment: The definition of Lyapunov stability is always about the equilibrium point only so how can we apply Lyapunov stability to trajectories?
Could you provide any reference books about Lyapunov stable trajectory?

Comment: Not always. The most common definition is given for equilibrium points, right (and this case is one of the most studied), but definition is much broader. It's also called "orbital stability"; see, for example, here: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Stability#Stability_of_General_Orbits